# tic tac toe game on android using AIDE app

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

I just started learning android coding from youtube

and I'm coding a tic tac toe game using an adroid app called AIDE

because of reasons

I created a layout with 9 buttons

and when the game starts the player click a button the android play a move and so on

but when there's is only one button left

the app stops and I can't click the last button

I'm using a public class called XO

```
import java.util.Random;

private char board[];
private final static int size=9;
private Random rand;

public final static char player1='X';
public final static char player2='O';
public final static char blank=' ';

public static int get_size()
{
    return size;
}//get size

XO()
{
    this.board=new char[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        board[i]=blank;
    }
    rand=new Random();
}//constructor

public void clear()
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        board[i]=blank;
    }
}//clear

public void setmove(char player,int loc)
{
    board[loc]=player;
}//set move

public int getComputerMove()
{
    int move;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(board[i]!=player1 && board[i]!=player2)
        {
            char curnt=board[i];
            board[i]=player2;
            if(checkforwin()==3)
            {
                setmove(player2,i);
                return i;
            }
            else
                board[i]=curnt;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(board[i]!=player1 && board[i]!=player2)
        {
            char curnt=board[i];
            board[i]=player1;
            if(checkforwin()==2)
            {
                setmove(player2,i);
                return i;
            }
            else
                board[i]=curnt;
        }
    }
    do
    {
        move=this.rand.nextInt(size);
    }while(board[move]==player1 || board[move]==player2);
    setmove(player2,move);
    return move;
}//get computer move

public int checkforwin()
{
    for(int i=0;i<=6;i+=3)
    {
        if(board[i]==player1 && board[i+1]==player1 && board[i+2]==player1)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        if(board[i]==player2 && board[i+1]==player2 && board[i+2]==player2)
        {
            return 3;
        }
    }//H

    for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        if(board[i]==player1 && board[i+3]==player1 && board[i+6]==player1)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        if(board[i]==player2 && board[i+3]==player2 && board[i+6]==player2)
        {
            return 3;
        }
    }//V

    if((board[0]==player1 && board[4]==player1 && board[8]==player1)||(board[2]==player1)&&(board[4]==player1)&&(board[6]==player1))
    {
        return 2;
    }

    if((board[0]==player2 && board[4]==player2 && board[8]==player2)||(board[2]==player2)&&(board[4]==player2)&&(board[6]==player2))
    {
        return 3;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(board[i]!=player1 || board[i]!=player2)
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}//check for win
```

and this is the main activity file

```
private XO game;
private Button buttons[];
private TextView info;
private TextView win;
private TextView tie;
private TextView lose;

private int wincounter=0;
private int tiecounter=0;
private int losecounter=0;

private boolean first=true;
private boolean gameover=false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    buttons=new Button[game.get_size()];
    buttons[0]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    buttons[1]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    buttons[2]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    buttons[3]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    buttons[4]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    buttons[5]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    buttons[6]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn7);
    buttons[7]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn8);
    buttons[8]=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn9);

    info=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
    win=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.winscount);
    tie=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tiescount);
    lose=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.losescount);

    win.setText(Integer.toString(wincounter));
    tie.setText(Integer.toString(tiecounter));
    lose.setText(Integer.toString(losecounter));

    game=new XO();
    startgame();
}

private void startgame()
{
    game.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++)
    {
        buttons[i].setText("");
        buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonOnclicklistner(i));
    }
    if(first)
    {
        info.setText(R.string.turn1);
        first=false;
    }
    else
    {
        info.setText(R.string.turn2);
        int move=game.getComputerMove();
        setmove(game.player2,move);
        first=true;
    }
}//start game

private class ButtonOnclicklistner implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private int loc;
    public ButtonOnclicklistner(int loc)
    {
        this.loc=loc;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(!gameover)
        {
            if(buttons[loc].isEnabled())
            {
                setmove(game.player1,loc);
                int state=game.checkforwin();
                if(state==0)
                {
                    info.setText(R.string.turn2);
                    int move=game.getComputerMove();
                    setmove(game.player2,move);
                    state=game.checkforwin();
                    gameover=false;
                }
                if(state==0)
                {
                    info.setText(R.string.turn1);
                    gameover=false;
                }
                else if(state==1)
                {
                    info.setText(R.string.restie);
                    tiecounter++;
                    tie.setText(Integer.toString(tiecounter));
                    gameover=true;
                }
                else if(state==2)
                {
                    info.setText(R.string.res1);
                    wincounter++;
                    win.setText(Integer.toString(wincounter));
                    gameover=true;
                }
                else if(state==3)
                {
                    info.setText(R.string.res2);
                    losecounter++;
                    lose.setText(Integer.toString(losecounter));
                    gameover=true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}//btn onclick class

private void setmove(char player,int loc)
{
    game.setmove(player,loc);
    buttons[loc].setEnabled(false);
    buttons[loc].setText(String.valueOf(player));
    if(player==game.player1)
    {
        buttons[loc].setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else
    {
        buttons[loc].setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}//set move
```

thanks for help

Comment: I think that AIDE like every IDE provides logs can you add them here ;-)

Comment: for some reason I can't access the logs

Comment: every time I open the logcat I get the this <run the app to see its log output>